# Replacing front and side concrete steps

Tags: concrete, outdoor, replacement

We are replacing our front and side concrete steps. Is it common for the contractor to use broken stone from the present steps to fill space on the new steps?

Comment: Yes it would be common

Comment: Comes down to either use them or pay to get rid of them and for more cement.